# Differential Equation: $\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{x-1}{2y}$

Tags: calculus

Solve the differential equation $\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{x-1}{2y}$.

Okay, I know how these work but I can't seem to find a way to integrate it. My instinct is to pull the $y$ over and then make it (integral) of $y$ and (integral) of $x-\frac{1}{2}$ but I know that isn't right.

Comment: Is that $\frac{1}{2y}$ or $\frac{1}{2}y$?

Comment: I made major edits to your question. If this does not reflect your intent, please tell me.

Comment: It does not. (x-1)/(2y)! Sorry!

Comment: @Lily Well in that case the answers given are incorrect. Please make your notation as clear as possible as to avoid wasting peoples time. I have left a hint for your corrected problem.

Comment: I've edited to include another answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answer to the original question**:

> Question: Solve $$\frac{dy}{dx} = x - \frac{1}{2} y$$

If you differentiate, you get
$$ \frac{d^2 y}{d x^2} = 1 - \frac{1}{2} x + \frac{1}{4} y
$$
and again,
$$ \frac{d^3 y}{d x^3} = - \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{4} x - \frac{1}{8} y = -\frac{1}{2} \frac{d^2 y}{d x^2}
$$
Hence $d^2y/dx^2$ is a function whose derivative is $-1/2$ times that function, so it must be in the form of
$$ \frac{d^2 y}{d x^2} = ce^{-(x-x_0)/2}
$$
Using the formula above,
$$ y = 4ce^{-(x-x_0)/2} + 2x - 4
$$
You can find $c$ and $x_0$ easily.

**Another question, another answer**

> Question: Solve $$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{x-1}{2y}$$

Using separation of variables,
$$ 2y\,dy = (x-1)dx
$$
Both sides can be integrated simultaneously, yielding
$$ y^2 = \int 2y\,dy = \int(x-1)\,dx = \frac{x^2}{2} - x + C
$$
You can then substitute the initial condition. If you want to solve for $y$, be careful of the signs when you square root.

**Edit**: The title and body of OP's question do not match, so I've added another possible answer.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{x-1}{2y} \Leftrightarrow 2y dy=(x-1)dx.$$

Integrate both sides. What do you get? Note that there will be two branches ($\pm$) of the final solution for $y$. An initial condition will allow you to see which solution you want.